# Get value from template to views

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a `Weather` API function that exists in `weather/views.py` And I have there a variable for a `town` of weather. (From which town I want to get weather values) I pass this value to function to get a weather information. After that I use `return JsonResponse(base)` to get the weather info to a static page, from where I'm taking it to a template with this `javascript` code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://192.168.71.152:8000/weather/", function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
      $("#weather").append(i+ " : " + field + "<br>");
       });
       });
    });
```

It all works fine but I also have a users from another town. This users have a `city` column in profile and DB. It looks like this `user.Profile.city`. And I would like to access that `city` for the current user in my template and pass it to that variable  `town` in `views.py`. So there will be a Weather with current location for the current user. Is it possible???

Im getting a weather info this way

```py
def weathere(*args, **kwargs):
        #read json data
        url = api.format(city = city_name, key = API_KEY)
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()
        jsonText = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
        python_obj = json.loads(jsonText)
```

And returning as `JSON` to `urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.weathere, name='weather'),
]
```

Comment: Yes, it is, simply pass the user `city` information in your view depending upon the user session and replace it with the `city_name`.

Comment: @user2906838 `depending upon the user session` how do you mean that? How can I access the user session

Comment: you should be able to know who is the current user in the first place so as to access his/her city.

Comment: @user2906838 so I should write a `request.user`?

Comment: Yes, probably, first of all, you should have the user_id or something unique to represent the user.  then you query that user in your User model, and get the `user.Profile.city`.